# "Check All" box currently checks everything on the page

Tags: jquery

I would like each "check all" box to only apply to the specific category it is for. Using the example below, when I click the check all box for Toyota it also checks the boxes for Ford. I would like the Toyota Check all box to only apply for Toyota cars. This code works when I write the script as separate items, but it stopped working when I created a separate JS file. I have several categories I will be using this code for so if there is a way to write it once as opposed to one for each category that would be appreciated as well.

```
<button class="accordion">Toyota</a></button>
<div class="panel">
<form action="CarPHPTest.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
<br/>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck" id="check_uncheck" /> Check         All/Uncheck All

<br/>
<div class="checkboxes">
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Camry id="check" /> Camry     <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Corolla id="check" /> Corolla   <br/>
</div> </p> </form>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Ford</a></button>
<div class="panel">
<form action="CarPHPTest.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
<br/>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck2" id="check_uncheck2" /> Check All/Uncheck All

<br/>
<div class="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Fusion id="check" /> Fusion  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Focus id="check" /> Focus   <br/>
</div> </p> </form>
</div>

JS File
// JavaScript Document
// The following script is for the check all/uncheckall feature 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
$("#check_uncheck").change(function() {
    if ($("#check_uncheck:checked").length) {
        $(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
$("#check_uncheck2").change(function() {
    if ($("#check_uncheck2:checked").length) {
        $(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: FYI - As it currently stands, you have both invalid tags (inside your buttons you have an anchor close tag without an open) and non-unique ID's for your checkbox elements.

Answer (score 0):

1. use this context to check for current changed checkbox
2. use closest(".panel") in selector to select only related checkboxes
3. fix id **ID should be unique**

```js
$("#check_uncheck").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest(".panel").find(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".panel").find(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
  }
});

"use strict";
$("#check_uncheck2").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest(".panel").find(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".panel").find(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Toyota</button>
<div class="panel">
  <form action="CarPHPTest.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <br/>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck" id="check_uncheck" /> Check All/Uncheck All

      <br/>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Camry id="check" /> Camry <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Corolla id="check" /> Corolla <br/>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Ford</button>
<div class="panel">
  <form action="CarPHPTest.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <br/>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck2" id="check_uncheck2" /> Check All/Uncheck All

      <br/>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Fusion id="check" /> Fusion <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Focus id="check" /> Focus <br/>
      </div>
  
  </form>
</div>
```

shorter version:

```js
$("#check_uncheck").change(function() {
  $(this).closest(".panel").find(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});

"use strict";
$("#check_uncheck2").change(function() {
  $(this).closest(".panel").find(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Toyota</button>
<div class="panel">
  <form action="CarPHPTest.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <br/>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck" id="check_uncheck" /> Check All/Uncheck All

      <br/>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Camry id="check" /> Camry <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Corolla id="check" /> Corolla <br/>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Ford</button>
<div class="panel">
  <form action="CarPHPTest.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <br/>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck2" id="check_uncheck2" /> Check All/Uncheck All

      <br/>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Fusion id="check" /> Fusion <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value=Focus id="check" /> Focus <br/>
      </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: And better yet the "Check All" inputs don't need unique IDs, they can share a common class and then you can just bind a single event handler. If you're keen, you can replace the if/else structure with `$(this).closest(".panel").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);`

Comment: @nnnnnn will add a demo for that

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still experiencing the same issue. The check all/ uncheck all feature is working with the script you suggested but it still checks everything on the page.